# Capacity of Kenmore gas dryer

Tags: dryer

This is Kenmore Dryer Model #78770100. I’m Trying to replace with the same size or with a bigger dryer how do I find out the capacity of this model?

Comment: Have you done a search of the internet? That's what one of us would have to do for you...

Comment: Use a dryer capacity calculator. https://calculator.academy/dryer-capacity-calculator/